# Background fixed phonegap

Tags: css, cordova, background

I have a problem with my background on Phonegap

I'm also using JQuery mobile

this is my css code witch generate the background

```
html, body {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
} 

.ui-page{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: url('../img/bg.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat fixed !important;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: MankSans;
    background-position:fixed;
    background-color:#102a3e;
}
```

When I scroll in the page my background stay at the top and but the part where my background isn't fetch stay white and I can't understand why

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `!important` from your style. This overrides your `background-color`. Just use

```
.ui-page {
    background: #102a3e url('../img/bg.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
}
```

Comment: thanks but the important was just to try to debug, I have the same problem without the impotant

Comment: @ant, I see, and did you try combining the color and image style like in my example (while using `!important`)?

Comment: Is there a working example to look at? Would be very interested what overrides `!important`.

Comment: the importent was just to try, because I'm using JQuery mobile and I thought they was maybe an other element. This is a a screen of the app problem http://www.heberger-image.fr/data/images/22158_Capture_dc_cran_du_Simulateur_iOS_5_avr._2013_01.32.04.png

Comment: Well, maybe there is. The only thing I can say for sure is that `background-color:#102a3e` gets overwritten by `background: url('../img/bg.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat fixed !important`. So that could be the reason why the `background-color` does not show up. If even `background: #102a3e url('../img/bg.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat fixed !important` does not work I have no idea what to do.